# CSS/JS Gradient-style opacity to fade out content

Tags: css, iframe, scroll, opacity, gradient

I'm wondering if there's a way to fade out (like a gradient) the opacity of an iframe and the content inside it. It's difficult to explain so a common example would be at the bottom of notification centre on Mountain Lion or iOs.

The whole idea is that when a user scrolls down (in an iframe) the content "fades out" at the bottom and it doesn't cut off with a straight line.

Not sure if this is possible with CSS or Javascript.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you want something like this:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/73603348/fadeout.html

What I've done in the past is create an overlay element at the bottom of the scrolling content. Pretty simple.

The markup:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
        [ content here ]
    </div>
    <div class="fader"></div>
</div>
```

The style:

```
.content {
    width: 600px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.fader {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0), #fff);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but where's the fadeout?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you don't want to load the whole jQuery library, you can write your own function to do the fadeout. Here's my own try to write such a function:

```
var ifrm = document.getElementById("your_frame"); //find your frame
function fadeOut(var duration) { //duration: how many millseconds you want the effect to take
    var step = 10 / duration; //step is how much the opacity will change each 10 milliseconds
    var curOpacity = 1; //at first the iframe is fully opaque.
    function animate() {
        if(curOpacity < step) {
             ifrm.style.opacity = 0; //we're done
             return;
        }
        ifrm.style.opacity = curOpacity;
        curOpacity -= step;
        setTimeout(animate, 10); //wait 10 millseconds and move to next step of animation
    }
    animate();
}
```

So suppose you want to fadeout for 1 second, then the initial fadeOut function call would be: `fadeOut(1000);`.

Again, I hope that helped you.

Comment: This is useful code, thx -- though I think the OP wanted a gradient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com). Example on how to fade out an element:

```
$("#your_iframe_id").fadeOut();
```

More details on how to use `fadeOut`: [jQuery API reference about fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).

Comment: I don't actually need to fade out the content as an animation, I need to basically blur the border out - if that makes any sense?

Comment: @user1599318 I'm sorry, I hardly get what you mean. Do you have an example somewhere of what's supposed to happen?